# Update needed on page "Cast Close And Reopen Votes"

Tags: bug

The screenshot and associated text at "Cast Close And Reopen Votes (https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) looks to be out of date. It should reflect the new closevote popup and new reasons.